# AX2012 - .Net assemblies from C# project are not updating on the AOS

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

We have deployed a AX2012 model that we developed in our dev environment into a production environment.

The model consists of a C# project, for which the settings are set to deploy to client and server.

After deployment it seems that the .NET assembly for the C# project is generated for the client vsassemblies folder (under c:\user\appdata\microsoft....) but it doesn't generate on the AOS server under C:\program files\Dynamics AX...\Server\bin\Vsassemblies folder".

The hot swapping setting is on. Is there a way to force the regeneration? Even restarting the AOS service doesn't recreate the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

should be something like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889192.aspx

"An assembly is copied to the client under these circumstances:

When a call is made from the client to managed code that is contained in the assembly.

When you access IntelliSense (at design time).

When you compile code that references the managed code assembly."

also, there are indications some of the documentation may be incorrect, and a bit of discussion about the server bit:
http://daxmusings.blogspot.com/2011/09/ax-2012-net-assembly-deployment.html

Comment: On one project we had some success forcing a .net transform dll to deploy by deleting the existing .dll and compiling the vs project again from the AOT

Answer (score 0):

We´ve got the same and many other Problems with .Net Projects in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

Do you use Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 and tried to check in and check out those Projects? The Solution Files will have a write lock, sometimes it can´t find the project to open it in Visual Studio... and so on...

I think the Developer Team from Microsoft Dynamics AX have a lot of work. Ah... I forget... Try to rename an already checked in AOT element. First it all looks good. But if another developer get latest changes. "There is already an object with origin id"... Great... :-/

It is really hard to manage a team with greater than 10 developers and many many problems.

Comment: We use TFS pretty extensively and although vs projects present some issues, no more really than any other part of the build: http://dynamicsaxbuild.codeplex.com/ http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2012/05/announcing-ax-tfs-build-library.html we also use a 'shared' workspace by creating a junction which may help with some issues like your rename scenario  but may introduce other issues